# next lowest number in mysql

Tags: mysql

how do i do a query that i want the next lowest number higher then a certain number

so for example if i have data like in the id step_number

```
1
3
4
5
6
```

if i just want the next highest number higher then 1...but i dont know the numbers they vary every time. I just know i need the next lowest number higher then a number. So in this case i would want 3 returned

```
select step_number from system_step_product where step_number > 1
order by step_number asc limit 1;
```

this works but is there a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution might be the most performant, but another solution that would work in other DB's would be:

```
SELECT MIN(step_number)
FROM system_step_product
WHERE step_number > 1
```

Indexing that column is also probably a good idea.

Comment: hehe, you were 46 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a better way; that's a pretty efficient way of doing it.

Also, do you have a reason for looking for a better way?  To quote Knuth,

> "Premature optimization is the root of
>   all evil."

Comment: This is not a good answer. This can be done SELECTing all values ORDERed ascending and LIMIT the number to 1 while using offset 1.

Comment: @tomasz: because it CAN be done that way doesn't in any way mean that it's a better way.  Also, note the edit / quote.

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
SELECT MIN(step_number) 
FROM system_step_product 
WHERE step_number > 1
```